# How truffle share (is it?) the addresses of the previously deployed contracts between migrations files?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

We have 2 migrations files (2,3) and in 2 we are deploying singletons contracts which later be used in the contracts we deploy on migrations file number 3.

How Truffle pass the address of the contract deployed on file 2 so the contracts that deploy on file 3 will use them as part of the deployment.

where I can the addresses of the deployed contracts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `truffle migrate` (aka `truffle deploy`) command executes the scripts inside the `migration` folder by alphabetic order (only those whose names start with a number).

Each one of these scripts should consist of:

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    ...
}
```

Truffle passes the `deployer` object to each one of these scripts, and this object "accumulates" the addresses of every contract deployed "along the way".

Thus, the `deployer` allows you to deploy contracts, as well as to retrieve the addresses of already-deployed contracts.

The documentation for it can be found [here](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer), and with more details [here](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer-api).